# Node.js REPL automatically declares underscore after a function declaration or function expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found out something weird about node.js today:

```
$ node
> console.log(_)
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:130:27)
    at bound (domain.js:257:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:270:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:277:12)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:812:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:101:10)
> function foo() {}
undefined
> console.log(_)
undefined
undefined
```

The same thing happens after I create a function expression:

```
$ node
> console.log(_)
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:130:27)
    at bound (domain.js:257:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:270:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:277:12)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:812:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:101:10)
> (function () {}())
undefined
> console.log(_)
undefined
undefined
```

It's pretty cool, and handy for function arguments which you intentionally want to leave as `undefined`, but why does it happen? I am using node version `v0.11.13` on Arch Linux.

Comment: `<rant>`The whole `_` thing is staggeringly frustrating when you're trying to use code that expects `_` to be the underscore library. The workarounds are hacky and don't really work; I recompiled to get rid of it--I don't use it anyway.`</rant>`

Comment: @DaveNewton but isn't repl suppose to work ONLY when you use node via command line? Not in a program itself? I'm confused because I came across this line "By executing node without any arguments from the command-line you will be dropped into the REPL" on the REPL docs.

Comment: +1 as well for bringing this feature into notice. I wouldn't have otherwise known or queried about this.

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything I'm not sure what you mean. If you type `node` you get the repl. But you can load arbitrary code into the repl, or cut-and-paste, etc. If your code includes the `_` symbol things break rather badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of [the repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features): `_` returns the result of the last expression.

Of course, in some cases - like the console.log you have - an expression will not return a result. But yeah it's a handy way to get the value of the last expression.

This only happens in the REPL of course - if you type up the same node program and run it from a file, `_` will be under your control.